# SQL Server - How To Converting Datetime Type From Nvarchar Type?

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2014-express

I have got two columns of `nvarchar`.

Sample data is:

```
column1='20180402', column2='134259'
```

My goal is to create a `datetime` type column by combining these two columns.

Like this: `'2018-04-02 13:42:59.000'`

How can I do that ?

Please, help me ?

Comment: if the format is always same then, `select format(20180402134259,'####-##-## ##:##:##.000')`

Comment: Refer the below URL:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218982/convert-nvarchar-to-datetime-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: @Mg45 any chance you can come and look at the brilliant answers below?

Comment: @Pரதீப் this format function is not fast, sorry.

Comment: @MyStack, I examined this url, but doesn't meet my need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @d varchar(50)='20180402',
        @t varchar(50)='134259'


select convert(varchar(50),convert(date,@d)) + ' '+ convert(varchar(50),dateadd(hour, (@T / 10000) % 100,
       dateadd(minute, (@T / 100) % 100,
       dateadd(second, (@T / 1) % 100,
       cast('00:00:00' as time(3))))) )
```

Comment: This has the benefit/drawback of accepting "times" like `999999` and `-1234`.

Comment: Hi, this DATETIMEFROMPARTS function is working successfully but when I use 'where LEFT(column1,4) >= CONVERT(NVARCHAR,YEAR(GETDATE())-1,112)' , I get this error ; 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

Comment: Hi huMpty duMpty, I want to continue this code. Also this title is an important to me. I waiting to your response immediately :)

Comment: @Mg45: Hi, are you writing this against a table? if it is please update your question with that table and some sample data so can see what you actually trying

Comment: select AUSVN, AUZTV from esp.VIQMEL WITH (NOLOCK) , Sample Data AUSVN AUZTV
20180402 131604
20180402 134259
20180402 134535
20180402 134701
20180402 134849

Comment: Also AUSVN and AUZTV  columns are nvarchar type.

Comment: What is column1 you referring to in your where condition.  20180402 or 131604

Comment: Yes, I want to write this against a table.

Comment: AUZVN = 20180402  , AUSTV = 131604

Comment: Your where statement is correct. But seem your column has data not in correct format. try this query and see what you get `Select *
from TableName
Where LEN(AUZVN) != 8`

Comment: Try just selecting `LEFT(column1,4)`

Comment: Yes, I tried that 'select distinct left(colum1,4) from my table'. There is a no problem here.

Answer (score 1):

You can either convert both strings to a `datetime` value and add them together to get your combined datetime or combine the strings and convert the result.

Note the time will need two `:` characters added to correctly parse:

```
select cast(d as datetime) + cast(stuff(stuff(t,5,0,':'),3,0,':') as datetime) as dt1
      ,cast(d + ' ' + stuff(stuff(t,5,0,':'),3,0,':') as datetime) as dt2
from (values('20180402','134259')) as v(d,t);
```

## Output

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|           dt1           |           dt2           |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2018-04-02 13:42:59.000 | 2018-04-02 13:42:59.000 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: @JeroenMostert  Way ahead of you :)

Comment: @JeroenMostert  5 seconds is a long time in SQL terms ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DATETIMEFROMPARTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetimefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
    SUBSTRING(column1, 1, 4),
    SUBSTRING(column1, 5, 2),
    SUBSTRING(column1, 7, 2),
    SUBSTRING(column2, 1, 2),
    SUBSTRING(column2, 3, 2),
    SUBSTRING(column2, 5, 2),
    0
)
FROM (VALUES
    ('20180402', '134259')
) v(column1, column2)
```

Comment: Hi, this DATETIMEFROMPARTS function is working successfully but when I use 'where LEFT(column1,4) >=  CONVERT(NVARCHAR,YEAR(GETDATE())-1,112)' , I get this error ; 'Cannot construct data type datetime, some of the arguments have values which are not valid.'

Comment: Could be an invalid year, month or month-day combination e.g. April 31. What value is causing the error?

Comment: I thinked it this, I looked. There is no such thing.

Comment: Yes, If I remove the where clause, it work successfully.

Comment: That is super weird. Still I believe there are invalid date/time values in your data. The answer assumes that the date and times are exactly 8 and 6 characters long. If they are less e.g. a time of `35959` instead of `035959` then it would trip.

Comment: I tried this; 'Select * from TableName Where LEN(column1) != 8' --> results = 0